# how to do right click and after that select copy option from the right click menu using down arrow keys in selenium python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-rc

as the subject says, i want to open web page, double click on word, after that once the word is selected to do mouse right click and select copy from the menu. till now i have the following code which do everything, open google, click on word, invoke the mouse right click but i have no idea how to do/use down arrow key to select copy. here is the code:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/?hl=en")

codeID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SIvCob"]')

ActionChains = ActionChains(driver)
ActionChains.double_click(codeID).perform()

ActionChains.context_click(codeID).perform();
```

i found some solutions in java and tried to implement those in python, but non of those worked, for example as this one (which I tried to use as a replacement for the last line of my code):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
ActionChains.context_click(codeID).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

please if someone can help me how to do this. thanks!

Comment: You can't access those browser-options from Selenium.  (At some point they restricted commands to the DOM only...)  You can set the clipboard yourself, though.  Just grab what you need using a selector, then set the clipboard using native code.

Comment: the problem is when i try to copy using keys and clipboard with pyperclip i get error: Element is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: use Selenium to get what it is you want to copy.  If it's text, there is a ".text" method.  You can then set the clipboards contents using pyperclip.copy('your_text')

Answer (score 1):

so in case anyone have the problem, this worked for me

```
codeID = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="message-htmlpart1"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/h2').text
pyperclip.copy(codeID)
```

and the code was copied in the clipboard.